# Reading and Writing to multiple Firestore Databases

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a iOS app written in swift, and I've run into a problem. I have the data storage for my app on one firebase/cloud firestore project, and the licensing for this app (among others) on another firebase/cloud firestore server. I'm able to get the iOS app working with my data storage firebase project, but cannot for the life of me access my licensing server to validate logins and check if products are licensed. Is there a "correct" way of doing this/"proper" way to do this? Thanks!

edit: My data firebase project is working fine, in my appdelegate I have this code (keys changed obv):

```
 let secondaryOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "appIDKEY",
                                               gcmSenderID: "senderID")
        secondaryOptions.apiKey = "apiKey"
        secondaryOptions.projectID = "project"
        secondaryOptions.bundleID = "com.bundle.id"
        secondaryOptions.clientID = "clientID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        secondaryOptions.databaseURL = "https://databaseurl.firebaseio.com"
        secondaryOptions.storageBucket = "url.appspot.com"
        secondaryOptions.appGroupID = nil

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        FirebaseApp.configure(name: "licensing", options: secondaryOptions)
```

then, in my Global Environment, I have this code:

```
 let licensingApp = FirebaseApp.app(name: "licensing")
    
    let licensingDB = Firestore.firestore(app: licensingApp)
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

On the "let licensingDB = Firestore.firestore(app: licensingApp)" line, I get the error:

> Cannot use instance member 'licensingApp' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The process is documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects. If you're having a hard time getting that to work, edit your question to show the [minimal complete steps, code and config that reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: just edited the original post

Comment: That seems to be a fairly common (not Firebase specific) problem: https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+use+instance+member+within+property+initializer%3B+property+initializers+run+before+%27self%27+is+available

Comment: yeah and i cant put my firebase db in a function, kind of defeats the purpose...for now im trying to figure out how to use the rest api to check licensing db, but even that has been a struggle...